# SQL Convert date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
declare @vaultdate varchar(10)
set @vaultdate = convert(date, getdate())-1
print @vaultdate
```

I got an error

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Can someone see what I have done wrong? Thank you

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Huh?  You code is really confusing.  You have mixed strings, integers, and dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the query, this will give you yyyy-mm-dd format

```
declare @vaultdate varchar(12)

set @vaultdate = getdate()-1

print CAST(convert(varchar,@vaultdate,20) AS DATE)
```

Comment: it works but need yyyy-mm-dd format. Please help. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you are using SQL Server.  If you want to work with dates, then use **dates** and their functions:

```
declare @vaultdate date;
set @vaultdate = dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate()));

print @vaultdate;
```

Comment: It's work but I used @vaultdate as varchar(10) then how do we correct this, Many thanks.

Comment: Don't store a date value in a string.  That is a bad SQL writing habit.

Comment: I understand, but I need to use it as varchar. can you help me out. Thanks

Comment: @ngoc . . . You should ask another question explaining what you want to actually do.

Comment: @ngoc So the real question you have is "How to get yesterday's date in a particular string format" (and please specify the exact format). I suggest to try searching the internet using that phrase. There is a high probability that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and that a different approach would be more suitable for your goal.

Comment: @ngoc . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have 1 parenthesis wrong and also you need to declare your variable as `datetime`. You don't even need convert:

```
declare @vaultdate datetime
set @vaultdate = getdate()-1
print @vaultdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff is totally correct when working with dates use date datatypes.  Using correct datatypes is one of the foundations of good SQL design.

If you need to convert the date to a string this should be done at point of use i.e. the presentation layer otherwise you can end up converting the date to a varchar for presentation then the presentation layer converting it to a separate format again because the requirements changed.

If you absolutely have to use a varchar then just add a couple of lines to Gordons very correct answer.

```
declare @vaultdatestring varchar(10);
declare @vaultdate date;
set @vaultdate = dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate()));

print @vaultdate;

set @vaultdatestring = convert(varchar(10), @vaultdate,103)
print @vaultdatestring;
```

There is a good resource on date formatting here: [Date and Time Conversions Using SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/)

If you could tell us why the varchar is needed we may be able to provide better suggestions.